# When I change the color of the toolbar is changing the color of the status bar also

Tags: android, colors, toolbar, statusbar

To change the color of the toolbar is changing the color of statusbar too. This happens when I change the background property of the toolbar .

File colors:

```
<color name="statusBarColor">#000000</color>
<color name="toolBarColor">#FFFFFF</color>
```

File styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item  name= "colorPrimary">@color/toolBarColor</item>
    <item  name= "colorPrimaryDark">@color/statusBarColor</item>
    <item  name= "colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

File toolbar.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
   app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
   app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
  android:background="@color/toolBarColor"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Soon the statusbar and the toolbar are white , but should be black and white respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Set the color of Statusbar when you change the color of Toolbar.
here is the snippet

```
Window window = activity.getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
window.setStatusBarColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.statusbar_color));
```